# Nuxt JS load components depending on API response

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, nuxt.js

I'm building a nuxt app to consume the wp rest API. In my fetch method I fetch information about needed components. I can't figure out how to then import all the components and render them. I've tried several methods, but I can't see to make it work.

Here's what works:

```
<component :is="test" :config="componentList[0]"></component><br>

export default {
  async fetch({ store, $axios }) {
    await store.dispatch("getPageBySlug", "home");
  },

  computed: {
    test() {
      return () => import('~/components/HeroIntro');
    }
  }
};
```

Ok so this is easy, nothing special - I could now import the component based on the slug etc. But I need to render multitple components and therefor im doing this:

```
<component
      v-for="component in componentList"
      :key="component.acf_fc_layout"
      :is="component.acf_fc_layout"
      :config="component">
</component>
```

along with this

```
export default {
  async fetch({ store, $axios }) {
    await store.dispatch("getPageBySlug", "home");
  },

  computed: {
    page() {
      return this.$store.getters.getPageBySlug("home");
    },
    componentList() {
      return this.page.acf.flexible_content;
    },
    componentsToImport() {
      for(const component of this.componentList) {
        () => import('~/components' + component.acf_fc_layout);
      }
    }
  }
};
```

All I'm getting is

> Unknown custom element: HeroIntro - did you register the
>   component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide
>   the "name" option

How do I archieve what im trying?

edit:

So, after a lot of trying, I could only make it work with using an extra component, "DynamicComponent":

```
<template>
  <component :is="componentFile" :config="config"></component>
</template>
<script>
export default{
  name: 'DynamicComponent',
    props: {
    componentName: String,
    config: Object
    },
    computed: {
        componentFile() {
            return () => import(`~/components/${this.componentName}.vue`);
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Now in Index.vue

```
<template>
  <main class="container-fluid">

    <DynamicComponent
      v-for="(component, index) in componentList"
      :key="index"
      :componentName="component.name"
      :config="component"
    />

  </main>
</template>

<script>    
export default {
  components: {
    DynamicComponent: () => import("~/components/base/DynamicComponent")
  }
```

I am not sure yet if this is optimal - but for now it works great - any input / opinions would be great!